# I am making a sudoku on c#

Tags: c#, matrix, time

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace testing_random
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int n = 4;
       int[,] a = new int[n,n];//declaring the matrix
        Random o = new Random();
        a[0,0] = o.Next(n);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)//filling the first line
        {
            int d = 1;
            while (d != 0)
            {
                a[i,0] = o.Next(n);
                d = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    if (a[i,0] == a[j,0])
                        d++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)//filing the first column
        {
            int d = 1;
            while (d != 0)
            {
                a[0, i] = o.Next(n);
                d = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    if (a[0, i] == a[0, j])
                        d++;
            }
        }
        for (int k = 1; k < n; k++)//filling the rest of the matrix
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            int d = 1;
            while (d != 0)
            {
                a[i, k] = o.Next(n);
                d = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    if (a[i, k] == a[j, k])
                        d++;
                for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                    if (a[i, k] == a[i, j])
                        d++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", a[i, j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        }
     }
}
```

The output should be a matrix of 4*4 where each column and each line contains each number once. 
The problem is when i run the code, not every time i get an output, i think the problem is not every set of first line and column can give a matrix as required the i get into an unending loop.
what i want to do is limit the running time of the application to 100 ms per example,so if the matrix is not filled,the program restarts
What piece of code am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the `while( d != 0 )` with a loop which counts up to a certain very large maximum number of iterations.  (Try 1000, 100000, whatever.)

Comment: Please let us know if it works.  Once it works, please "accept" the answer which was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to randomly insert numbers between 1-4 in the first line of the array? If so there is a much easier way to do it.

You can generate the 4 numbers to be inserted into the array and then just look through the first line of the array and set each value.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   a[i, 0] = randomNumbers[i];
}
```